# Laravel inertia vue js showing blank page when export default is added

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, primevue

I have the following component where I am using PrimeVue Datatable and ConfimDialog

```
<template>
    <Head title="Patients" />
    <AppLayout>
        <template #header>
            <div class="p-2">
                <div>
                    <span class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200 leading-tight">Patients</span>
                    <span class="h-fit min-h-full flex justify-end" style="margin-top: -24px;">
                        <a href="/pateints/create">
                            <PrimaryButton class="ml-2 float-right" type="button">
                                <i class="pi pi-plus"></i>&nbsp;
                                Add Patient
                            </PrimaryButton>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
        <div class="py-2">
            <ConfirmDialog></ConfirmDialog>

            <Button icon="pi pi-check" label="Confirm"></Button>
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div v-if="$page.props.flash.notification" class="alert">
                    {{ $page.props.flash.notification }}
                </div>
                <div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                    <div class="p-2 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
                        <div class="p-2">
                            <DataTable :value="$page['props']['patients']" responsiveLayout="scroll" :paginator="true"
                                paginatorTemplate="FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink CurrentPageReport RowsPerPageDropdown"
                                :rows="10" dataKey="id" :rowsPerPageOptions="[10, 25, 50]"
                                currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries">
                                <Column field="name" header="Name" :sortable="true"></Column>
                                <Column field="gender" header="Gender" :sortable="true"></Column>
                                <Column field="contact_number" header="Contact Number" :sortable="true"></Column>
                                <Column field="email_id" header="Email" :sortable="true"></Column>
                                <Column field="city" header="City" :sortable="true"></Column>
                                <Column header="Actions">
                                    <template #body="slotProps">
                                        <span>
                                            <a :href="'pateints/edit/' + slotProps.data.id">
                                                <i class="pi pi-user-edit"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <a href="/pateints/delete"><i class="pi pi-trash"></i></a>
                                        </span>
                                    </template>
                                </Column>
                            </DataTable>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </AppLayout>
</template>
<script>
import { Head, Link, useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue';
import DataTable from "primevue/datatable";
import Column from "primevue/column";
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue';
import { ref, onMounted, defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useConfirm } from "primevue/useconfirm";
import ConfirmDialog from 'primevue/confirmdialog';
import Button from 'primevue/button';

export default {
    methods: {
        delete() {
            this.$confirm.require({
                message: 'Are you sure you want to proceed?',
                header: 'Confirmation',
                icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
                accept: () => {
                    //callback to execute when user confirms the action
                },
                reject: () => {
                    //callback to execute when user rejects the action
                },
                onShow: () => {
                    //callback to execute when dialog is shown
                },
                onHide: () => {
                    //callback to execute when dialog is hidden
                }
            });
        },
    }
}

</script>
```

Before adding the `export default` everything is working fine. But once I add the function, it is showing a blank page. It is showing the following warnings in the console.

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:40 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: Head
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <Index jetstream= {canCreateTeams: false, canManageTwoFactorAuthentication: true, canUpdatePassword: true, canUpdateProfileInformation: true, hasEmailVerification: true, …} auth= {user: null} errorBags= []  ... > 
  at <Inertia initialPage= {component: 'pateints::Index', props: {…}, url: '/pateints', version: '6666cd76f96956469e7be39d750cc7d9'} initialComponent= {__hmrId: 'c2a09695', __file: '/Resources/Pages/Index.vue', inheritAttrs: false, setup: ƒ, render: ƒ, …} resolveComponent=fn<r>  ... > 
  at <App>
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. I have tried both options API and Composition API, but both gives the same result. I am new to Laravel inertia and Vue and so it will be helpful if someone can point out what I am missing here. It is same for all the components that I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is still helpful 2 months later ...

I too was surprised when Webpack didn't catch the error, so the console did.

Looks to me like you need to register your components (including Head) in script like so:

```
export default {
  // ...
  components: {
    Head,
    Link,
    // and so on ...
  },
  props: [
// ...
```

Use the "components" option in Options API, "script setup" or also "components" in plain "script" for Composition API. btw, this is a common Vue thing, not just with Inertia.
[vue.js Component Registration](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html)